# Google has stored generated url

Tags: url

In our company, we are generating validation certificates for customer bookings. They are accessible over internet and url depends on the system generated policy number and few other parameters related to the booking.

We are generating a encrypted number using those parameters and set the url for the validation certificate. Final url is like:

```
www.mysite.com/policy/doc/validation_certificate?id=encrypted_number
```

One of this url is picked under a google search. Can some one help me on this to avoid picking these urls in a google search.

Comment: This question belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options.

The best one would be to access restrict the url as appropriate, denying it from being visible at all without being logged in.

If that is not an option, use a `robots.txt` file and a `<meta name="robots">` tag:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2956/how-to-stop-certain-urls-from-being-indexed